# Answering よくえいがをみますか。(Genki I Workbook)

Tags: grammar

What's the correct way of answering よくえいがをみますか。with "No, only sometimes."?

I am guessing it is incorrect to say いいえ、ときどきをみます。as いいえ should follow by negatives instead of affirmatives?

How about いいえ、よくえいがをみません。ときどきみます。?

Answer (score 1):

> I am guessing it is incorrect to say いいえ、ときどきをみます。as いいえ should follow by negatives instead of affirmatives?

That is incorrect because you've made ときどき the object of みます.

いいえ、ときどきしかみません。

would be OK. いいえ、ときどきみます is a bit strange unless someone is asserting very strongly that you watch films a lot.

Comment: Ah, the を was a typo! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could answer with

> いいえ、[滅多]{めっ・た}にみません　→　No, I (only) seldom watch them.